# Windows Server 2016: No network cable detected after reboot

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, nic, reboot

we recently made the 'mistake' to reboot one of our servers (INTEL Server Barebone R2312WFTZS S2600WFT). All went fine but after the system was up and running we could not connect via network. Checking directly at the server we could see that windows believes that there is no network cable plugged in.

The two NICs are connected to a Netgear 10GB switch via CAT7 cables.

We tried the following without a solution:

- change network cables
- change network ports (different switch)
- switching between static IP and DHCP
- restart several network related windows services
- boot in recovery mode with network support
- updating driver of network adapter

I've searched the web, StackExchange and other communities but did not find anything. At the moment we are totally clueless so any help will be really appreciated!

(Please forgive me if I missed some important informations - until now I've been only a software developer who rarely works with server administration, so only basic knowledge is available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally we found the reason:

After we hired an external specialist we found out that the on-board NICs are physical broken. After installing a PCI network card we were able to get network access back.

We updated the BIOS, all drivers, used an usb-boot-stick - none of them were able to reactivate the NICs...

Fortunately the mainboard has a guarantee from Intel so we will get replacement soon.